# Pagebreak after titlepage

Tags: page-breaking, titles, abstract

I have now made a titlepage in my document using

```
\begin{titlepage}
stuff
\end{titlepage}
```

and that is fine, but now when I tried to insert a blank page after the titlepage and before

```
\begin{abstract}
stuff
\end{abstract}
```

Latex will not listen and put a blank page there! Can someone help me to do this?

P.S. I have no idea whether using the titlepage environment is "good" practice when using Latex, so if anyone has comments on that, they are most welcome.

P.P.S. The relevant stuff from my preamble is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
```

P.P.P.S. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}

%irrelevant stuff

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

some nonsense

\end{titlepage}

%Tried \pagebreak,\clearpage,\newpage,combinations thereof

\begin{titlepage}

Abstract 

\end{titlepage}

%Tried as above

\tableofcontents

Some more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: What code are you attempting to use to insert a new page? `\clearpage`, `\newpage`, `\pagebreak` all are different, but should all force a new page. We need more code to see what the problem is. Try to make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which shows your problem, with no unnecessary code.

Comment: Edited and added.

Comment: How about `\cleardoublepage`? Also, to answer you question about `titlepage` we would need some info about what exactly you want your titlepage to look like, is `\maketitle` satisfying?

Comment: That worked. I don't like maketitle so much (but maybe I just don't know how to work its options) because I want to be able to customize what I write on the titlepage and where.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt,titlepage]{report}`

Answer (score 1):

Using `\cleardoublepage` will here fill in a blank page. It ensures that the next content, whatever it might be, is on the rightside.

**Full Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}

%irrelevant stuff

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

some nonsense

\end{titlepage}

\cleardoublepage

\begin{titlepage}

Abstract 

\end{titlepage}

%Tried as above

\tableofcontents

Some more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `openleft` option for `report`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `report` class, but `book`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\pagestyle{plain}

%irrelevant stuff

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

some nonsense

\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}

Abstract 

\end{titlepage}

%Tried as above

\tableofcontents

Some more text

\end{document}
```